# How to select a week in the Flutter Date Range Picker but without using syncfusion _flutter_datepicker

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to select a week in the flutter date range picker but without using syncfusion package. How to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to implement a third party package , flutter provide better date picker. you can use flutter date picker.

```
showDatePicker(context: context, initialDate: initialDate, firstDate: firstDate, lastDate: lastDate);
```

Comment: But how I achieved when I click any date for suppose If I select 10th date does it auto select the entire week ?

Comment: yes, for that  you have to change the values of first and last date accordingly

Comment: Can you please help me I have tried many ways but nothing works.